# Google Analytics: setting custom visitor segments

Tags: cookies, google-analytics

I am currently trying to track non registered and registered users on a site using custom visitor segments via Google Analytics.

http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingVisitorSegments.html

This involves adding a cookie to the user if they are a registered user and on a members only page via some google analytics authored Javascript, this is done when the user is logged in. This cookie then remembers the user as registered when they revisit the site.

This is the standard line of code that set's the coookie:

```
pageTracker._setVar("RegisteredUsers")
```

This method has a flaw in that "For visitor session calculations, the value chosen is the first association of the session." this means, I think, I can only set one value, and if a non member visits the site, then registers, they are then counted and tracked as a member. This makes it difficult to track conversions, and non member journeys on the site.

I am wondering is there a way to track non members and members, and differentiate between a non member who has registered in the session, and a returning registered member. Perhaps using some custom written Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with 3 advanced segments and goal conversion on your registration process:

1. "registred" custom var AND no "registration" goal conversion --> old members
2. "registred" custom var AND "registration" goal conversion --> new members
3. no "registred" custom var --> not members